# Get min/max value from array based on condition

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = [ [ 'Name' => 'Product 1', 'Quantity' => 0, 'Price' => 70  ], 
           [ 'Name' => 'Product 2', 'Quantity' => 2, 'Price' => 100 ],
           [ 'Name' => 'Product 3', 'Quantity' => 2, 'Price' => 120 ] ];

echo min( array_column( $array, 'Price' ) ); // 70
```

It does get me the `min` price, but I also want to check for quantity, in that case `100` would be the lowest.

Is there an elegant way to do this without looping?

Comment: Are you trying to find the lowest price where quantity is greater than 0?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator Yes, exactly.

Comment: Array column is a waste of memory. Loop through the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**array_filter** to the rescue!

Before checking for min, remove the elements from your array which have Quantity set to 0.

```
echo min( array_column( array_filter($array,function($v) { 
return $v["Quantity"] > 0; }), 'Price' ) );
```

To make it more readable

```
$filtered=array_filter($array,function($v) { return $v["Quantity"] > 0; });
echo min( array_column( $filtered, 'Price' ) );
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/696134)**

And an old-school version without all the closures

```
foreach($array as $v)
{
   if($v["Quantity"]>0 && (!$min || $v["Price"]<$min))
   $min=$v["Price"];
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/696152)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the array index with 0 quantity using [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function($v) {
    return $v['Quantity'];
});

echo min( array_column( $filtered_array, 'Price' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $array = [[ 'Name' => 'Product 1', 'Quantity' => 0, 'Price' => 70], 
             ['Name' => 'Product 2', 'Quantity' => 2, 'Price' => 100],
             ['Name' => 'Product 3', 'Quantity' => 2, 'Price' => 120]];

    $price=array();

    for($i=0; $i<count($array);$i++){
      $price[$i]=$array[$i]['Price'];  
    }

    echo  min($price); //70
```